# IdentityBuilder does not contain a definition for 'AddEntityFrameworkStores

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .netcore 3.1. While using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;    
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;    
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;    
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;    
///using AspNetCore3JWT.Data;    
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;        
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;    
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Jwt.Data;

namespace Jwt
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers()
                   .AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()

                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error:

[image: error-image-code]

Comment: I think you mised one of this usings: **using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;** or
**using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;**

Comment: I am using namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder. still, I am getting error

Comment: please, provide code from your Startup class.

Comment: I have updated the startup.cs code

Comment: Have you installed [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/) from NuGet?

Comment: No, now I installed, It is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I just upgraded a project to .net core 3.1, and had to change the following line from

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext>();
```

To

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddUserStore<DBContext>();
```

OR

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

Comment: This worked for me replacing AddDefaultIdentity with AddIdentity: services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

Answer (score 16):

In addition to installing the package [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore) per [serpent5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056684/identitybuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-addentityframeworkstores/64107149#comment106215297_60056684), I also had to install the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI`.

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure you inherit from IdentityDbContext not DbContext only**

Comment: Can you elaborate on this any? Source code? filename example? This seems like it's a good lead.

Answer (score 0):

check the DbContext if it inherits from IdentityDbContext.

```
    public class AppUserDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {}
```

if it does not, install the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.